# Calculating Overall Best Game in Guessing Game

Tags: java, while-loop

SI wrote a java code for a numbers guessing game. The entire thing is pretty much done. It works by choosing a random number then asking the user for console inputs and then saying whether that is higher or lower than the random number. Once you guess it, it then asks if you want to play again. When you finally say no to this (be it one game or several) it prints out your Overall results including total games, total guesses, avg guesses/game and your best game. I have everything worked out except I cant figure out how to make it print your overall best game.

```
import java.util.*; //so I can use scanner

public class GuessingGame {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   
      Random rand = new Random ();
      int max = 100;
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int guess;
      boolean play = true;
      int totalGames = 0;
      int totalGuesses = 0;
      
      System.out.println("Can you guess the word?");
      System.out.println("I am sure you cannot guess!");
      System.out.println("Go ahead and try!");
      System.out.println();
      
      while (play) {
      
         System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and " + max + "...");
         int numberToGuess = rand.nextInt(max) + 1;
         int numberOfTries = 0;
         boolean win = false;
         while (!win) {
         
            System.out.print("Your guess? ");
            guess = input.nextInt();
            numberOfTries++;
             
            if (guess == numberToGuess) {
               win = true;  
            } else if (guess > numberToGuess) {
               System.out.println("It's lower.");
            } else if (guess < numberToGuess) {
               System.out.println("It's higher.");
            }      
            input.nextLine();
         }
         if (numberOfTries == 1) {
            System.out.println("You got it right in " + numberOfTries + " guess!");
         } else {
            System.out.println("You got it right in " + numberOfTries + " guesses!");
         }   
            totalGames++;
            totalGuesses+= numberOfTries;
            System.out.print("Do you want to play again? ");
                       
            String answer = input.nextLine();
            char firstLetter = answer.charAt(0);
            if (firstLetter == 'y' || firstLetter == 'Y') {
            play = true;  
            } else {
            play = false;              
         }  
         System.out.println();           
      }
      System.out.println("Overall results:");
      System.out.println("Total games = " + totalGames);  
      System.out.println("Total guesses = " +  totalGuesses);
      System.out.println("Guesses/game = " + totalGuesses/totalGames);
      System.out.println("Best game = ");
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the best score, which is the lowest number of guesses.

```
int bestGame = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // at the top
bestGame = Math.min(bestGame, numberOfTries); // at the end of your inner while loop
```

The worst possible score is the highest number of guesses, which is limited by Integer.MAX_VALUE, so you start there.

Comment: I get an error, can't find symbol using `int bestGame = Integer.Max_INT;`

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner is more likely to learn something!

Comment: Thank you so much! This was killing me last night I appreciate the quick responses!

Answer (score 0):

To fit into the code you have already written, You could

1. Create a new 'global' variable, for example `int bestGame = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`.
2. Whenever the user is done with a game do a check if the current `numberOfGuesses` is smaller than the current `bestGame`, and if it is, then overwrite `bestGame` with the current `numberOfGuesses`.
3. At the end, you simply need to output `bestGame`.

Comment: When can `numberOfGuesses` be smaller than `bestGame` if you initialize it with **0**? :P

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the best game you need a keep track of the best best after each game, such as a variable that checks it there is a new best game after each game.

Answer (score 0):

By the best game u mean minimum number of tries needed to answer is the best game.

```
  /* int mintries,bestgame,gamenumber=0;
   bestgamenumber=0;mintreies=Integer.MAX_VALUE:*/
```

Add the above lines above your while(play)

```
        gamenumber++;
     /*if(mintries>numberOfTries)
        {
           mintries=numberOfTries;//update mintries
           betgame=gamenumber;
        }*/
```

Add the if condition just before closing while(play).
So it will be like

```
         int mintries;
         mintreies=Integer.MAX_VALUE:  
         int gamenumber=0;
          int bestgamenumber=0//if you want to print the which game is the   best game(!st,2nd,3rd..)    ;        
         while(play)
         { 
             // do all your stuff
              gamenumber++;
              if(mintries>numberOfTries)
              {
                 mintries=numberOfTries;//update mintries
                 bestgamenumber=gamenumber;
               } 
        }
           }
          System.out.println("Game number +bestgamenumber+"was the best game with"+ mintries+"tries);
```

I am considering that you want to print which game (1st,2nd,3rd)is best and minimum tries made to guess the best game.Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: actually no that's more complicated than what I was trying to do. I was simply trying to get it to print your best score under the Best Game category. So whatever game had the lowest amount of guesses that would be the "Best game" and it would print however many guesses that was. I figured it out but thank you for the help thats pretty useful for future reference.